# SAS DS2 Varchar Issue

Tags: sas, varchar, nvarchar

I have a method in DS2 which gets the html content for a given url.

As far as I understand, DS2 doesn't have character limitation like in Data Step and we can mention number of characters next to the varchar datatype.

If you check the body variable below, I have increased the length to store the entire page but the output shows only a part of the html body. Can anyone please let me know what is wrong ?

```
     method getData(nvarchar(1024) url) returns nvarchar;
        declare package http h();

        declare nvarchar(99999999) body;
        declare int rc status;

        h.createGetMethod(url);
        h.executeMethod();

        status = h.getStatusCode();

        if status eq 200 then
            do;
                h.getResponseBodyAsString(body, rc);
            end;

        return body;
    end;
```

Comment: How are you showing the output?

Comment: Writing to the logs and to the file.

Comment: And what length is it being truncated at?

Comment: no of bytes : 9042  and no of characters :8986

Comment: Then you have some other problem.  I can get 70k characters easily using the exact code above, though of course only 32k can be output to a SAS dataset.

Comment: Could that be encoding ? Can you please let me know the URL you are testing with Joe ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114765/discussion-between-joe-and-aks).

Comment: Figured out that the regex I am using is behaving weirdly. Sorry about that Joe. Thanks for your time !!

Comment: Glad you figured out your issue.